# what's the over head per node and per edge for single entry in neo4j

Tags: graph, jvm, neo4j

I have a graph of integers (say 12 bytes).
  Each node has 200 outgoing edges. 
  I have 100*10^6 nodes.

Given the 'key' weights 12b what is the total size, when it is represented in neo4j?
  Whats is the cost of edge?

It this size of neo4j possible to query? --- I mean of course some internal constrains, the time of the query would express I/O performance (I guess?).

I am interested in query: which node is connected to node X.

What about JVM limits? Any chance to bump into something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current limits on size is [32 billion nodes, 32 billion relationships and 64 billion properties](http://blog.neo4j.org/2011/03/neo4j-13-abisko-lampa-m04-size-really.html). In general query time is about how much of the graph needs to be touched, the size of the graph matters very little. Depending on your queries, you may have less use of the caching and then it's all down to I/O performance. The documentation on [caches in Neo4j](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/configuration-caches.html) should give you some hints on disk/memory costs.